# Accept socket connection in background while displaying Qt GUI in C++

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, asynchronous, serversocket

### My problem

This function is supposed to [`accept()`](https://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#acceptthank-you-for-calling-port-3490.) a connection from a client and return the new file descriptor `newfd`. The problem is that waiting for a connection freezes the Qt GUI.

```
int tcp_connect(int sockfd)
{
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size = sizeof client_addr;
    int newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);

    return newfd;
}
```

### My attempts

I've tried executing the function asynchronously using [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), but the user interface still freezes until a connection from a client is accepted.

```
std::future<int> future (std::async(tcp_connect, sockfd));
int newfd = future.get();
```

I have also tried using [`QTConcurrent::run`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html), but it yields the same result.

```
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(tcp_connect, sockfd);
int newfd = future.result();
```

Let me know if further information is required to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has `QTcpSocket` with asyncronous signal-slot api, you can use that. Or you can use `QThread`.

Comment: Okay thanks I will definitely check out `QTcpSocket`. Can you point me to a simple example of how to use it?

Comment: [fortuneclient](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html) [loopback](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-loopback-example.html) [network-chat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-network-chat-example.html)